# python character encoding pc mac

Tags: python, windows, macos, character-encoding

I am admittedly not well-versed in character encoding issues.
I've written a script that uses os.path.isfile() to check whether a path is a file before proceeding.

On Macos Python 2.7.10, I have had no problems, but I just tried using the script on a Windows10 for the first time with Python 3.6.3, and ran into isfile() returning false on paths that definitely are files, and were recognised as such on Macos.

Investigating, I found that an offending file lists differently with os.listdir() on Macos than it does on Windows10.  It has a special character in it, and here is how the special character is reproduced on the two operating systems:

PC: '\uf022'
Macos: '\xef\x80\xa2'

I assume this is relevent to why os.path.isfile() is not liking the Windows10 representation of the file.  To test this, I did the following on Windows10:

- change directory into the file's directory,
- launch the interactive python shell
- import os
- perform os.listdir()
- perform os.path.isfile(*file name exactly as os.listdir listed it*)

This returns FALSE.
So I'm stumped.  Any help would be appreciated!

---

Edit for extra clarity, the following on Windows10 Python 3.6.3:

```
>>> files = os.listdir()
>>> files[5]
'1955 shark - Oz Huntly\uf022Noel.jpg'

>>> os.path.isfile( files[5] ) 
FALSE

>>> os.stat( files[5] )
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 
'1955 shark - Oz Huntly\uf022Noel.jpg'
```

Finally a clue that this is probably not even Python related.  I tried copying the files through Explorer, and it appears the OS itself can't find the files it is clearly representing as being present, complete with normal looking file size and other assorted metadata.  Only the two files with this special character are flummoxing Windows...  Seeing as this does not strictly seem to be a Python problem in the end, feel free to ignore/move this question....

Edit - As Eryksun pointed out in the comments: this is probably the fault of the Paragon HFS+ drivers I am using to allow Windows10 to read an HFS+ formatted drive.  I'm passing this on to Paragon.  Thank you for your help Eryksun!

All the best,
Malcolm

Comment: This is your character. See the python thing for how to type it. http://www.charbase.com/f022-unicode-invalid-character

Comment: Python 2 defaults to byte strings, and the MacOS file-system encoding is UTF-8. Python 3 uses Unicode strings. The name is `"\uf022"`, not `"uf022"`. That's a `\u` Unicode escape with the 4-digit hexadecimal ordinal for the Unicode code point U+F022, which is not a regular assigned character. It's a code point in a [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas).

Comment: Thanks for your responses...  Sorry I omitted to include the backslash in '\uf022'.  I am still stumped because I expect isfile() to return true if I feed it precisely the output of os.listdir() for that file?

Comment: `isfile` stats the file, which can fail, in which case it ignores the error and returns false. Try `os.stat(files[5])`.

Comment: Thanks Eryksun - I've updated the post with the result.  Looks like python really can't find the file, strangely enough.

Comment: How is the drive formatted -- NTFS, FAT32, etc -- or is it a network share?

Comment: Hello again - the drive is HFS+ and is being accessed via the Paragon drivers - perhaps another layer that could cause problems?  I've updated to the question to include some evidence this isn't really a Python problem since the OS itself seems to get its knickers in a bunch over the two files with special characters in their name as well.  I do appreciate your time trying to troubleshoot this with me!  I'm going to move the project over to NTFS drives and move on from there.  All the best! M

Comment: It's up to the file-system driver. If you're not using a driver that's written by Microsoft and distributed with Windows, then you can't really fault the OS. For example, a create/open operation calls the driver with an `IRP_MJ_CREATE` I/O request, with the filename passed as a wide-character string (UTF-16LE, but more permissive by allowing lone surrogate codes). This request could fail with various status codes that get mapped to WinAPI `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2), but typically it's `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND`. Possibly the driver has a bug that rejects the U+F022 character in the name.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks for the insight there Eryksun.  I'll send Paragon a link to this page!

Answer (score 0):

I am too new to upvote those who helped elucidate this.
Eryksun pointed towards a probable answer in the comments: it is probably the fault of the Paragon HFS+ drivers I am using to allow Windows10 to read and write to HFS+ formatted drives.  He explains his thinking better than I can, but basically if the driver code encounters a none zero status while creating an open request for the file, that could be mapped to Windows' 'file not found' error, and so block access to files that are actually there and valid.  The special character U+F022 could cause that non-zero status during the file open process.
Please upvote Eryksun in the comments if you find this answer useful.